# Morris Donut Chart label is showing undefined error

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, morris.js, donut-chart

I am using Morris Donut chart to display the progress. I am getting the count of status correctly. But instead of Label it is showing undefined in the donut chart.

[Morris Donut Chart Showing Undefined Error as Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3ycp.png)

```
    var dtData = _.groupBy(jsonData, "status");
    var keys = [];
    keys = Object.keys(dtData);
    dtArr = [];

        for (var n = 0; n < keys.length; n++) {

            dtArr.push({
                name: '' + keys[n] + '', value: '' + dtData[keys[n]].length + '',

            });

        }
    Morris.Donut({ element: 'dashboard-donut-8', 
data: dtArr, 
label: 'name', 
value: 'value', 
colors: ['#33414E', '#E04B4A', '#1caf9a', '#95b75d'], 
resize: true });
```

I am getting the value correctly. But getting as undefined for label.

Please help me on this

Thank You

Comment: hi. Few questions - which version - SharePoint online or On-Premise? If SharePoint Online then classic web part or modern SPFx? also if you can put dummy JSON data in your sample above, we would be able to verify this.

Comment: Hi, I am using SharePoint On-Premise. Actually I have created a Dasboard .net website and fetching data from sharepoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the key **label** instead of **name**

`label: '' + keys[n] + '', value: '' + dtData[keys[n]].length + '',`

Comment: Hi Pierre,
Thanks for your comment.
Let me try